# Show/hide between two elements randomly onload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two elements, `.a` and `.b`. By default, both elements have `display: none`. I want to make **one of the two** appear randomly when the page loads. Sometimes `.a` appears, sometimes `.b` appears, by giving the class `.c` which will provide `display: block`.

This is what I have tried but failed because sometimes both are shown and hidden together:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var scenario = Math.random() < .5 ? "c" : "d";

  document.querySelector(".a").classList.add(scenario);
  document.querySelector(".b").classList.add(scenario);

});
```

```css
.a, .b {display:none}
.a.c, .b.c {display:block}
```

```html
<div class='a'>aaa</div>
<div class='b'>bbb</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you calculate the `scenario` randomly, but then apply it to both elements.

To do what you require use the `Math.random` logic to determine which element ot target, either `.a` or `.b`, then add the `c` class to that element only. Try this:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var selector = Math.random() < .5 ? ".a" : ".b";
  document.querySelector(selector).classList.add('c');
});
```

```css
.a, .b { display: none; }
.a.c, .b.c { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="a">aaa</div>
<div class="b">bbb</div>
```